# How to embed following href javascript code to a button in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am creating a asp.net website. It has a file upload button. Uploading href works fine with following code. But i want to embed this code in a button.

```
<a href="javascript:$('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').fileUploadStart()">Start Upload</a>
```

here is the button that i want to embed above javascript code. and also i want the click event to this button.

```
<input type="button"  value="upload" runat="server"  name="btnBeforeOk" onserverclick="btnBeforeOk_ServerClick" />
```

This is my c# code for the above button

```
        protected void btnBeforeOk_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Response.Write("<script type=\"text / javascript\">window.location.href = \"javascript:$('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').fileUploadStart()\"; </ script > ");
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "onlick();", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "onlick()", true);
    }
```

I'm calling following javascript function from that button's C# code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function onlick() {
    location.href = "javascript:$('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').fileUploadStart()"
    alert("Alert works well but above code is not running")
}
            </script>
```

Alert part of this code is working well. but that small href code above the alert is not running well as it is working well with `'<a href>'` tag in asp.net. I also tried to run that small code with "window.location" and "windows.location.href". but it is not working. i was searching on google for 2 days and did many solutions. nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

That line of code isn't working because all you're doing is setting location.href, equal to the value of a string literal (the idea of setting window.loaction.href, to a string with a value of a valid url is the right course of action), however the string literal in this case is not a a valid url.

It works inline in your html, because the string is interpreted as javascript, it executes the line of code, and that line of code produces a string with a value of the url that you want. However in this case, that line of code is already in a script, and is interpreted so.

Therefore in order for the it to be executed, you need it to not be a string literal, as it currently is, but rather be it's own line of actual code.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onlick() {
        window.location.href = $('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').fileUploadStart()
    }
</script>
```

This will execute the "fileUploadStart" function on the jquery object returned by your jquery selector, i.e. the "$('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>')" part of your code.

Which should presumably return the url you're after.